# Patterns and things

Tags: pattern

This is my first post on this forum! Credit goes to Goleman's 2014 IQ Test, problems 12, 20, 15, 19, and 18.

If this is plagiarism please let me know

If this is too easy please let me know :)

If I shouldn't post this many puzzles at once please let me know :) :)

Any feedback would be appreciated :) :) :)
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I'm *pretty* sure that putting multiple questions into one question post isn't kosher. (I also think that all of the text except for "Credit goes to Goleman's 2014 IQ Test, problems 12, 20, 15, 19, and 18." really should be in the comments instead of the question body, but I'm less sure about everyone's opinion on that)

Comment: @DennisMeng Compound questions are not a problem IMHO. Half the puzzles on this site require making a chain of suggestions, assumptions and guesses to answer a chain of questions. Here, OP gives a bunch of chain segments, which has its own merits.

Comment: @kiwialacorn: The OP is not 'problematic' or anything, but what you should keep in mind is *why* you are posting here. It is not the aim here to get a 'collection' of puzzle on this site. Generally speaking, posts which either need *help* with a puzzle solution, are *about* a puzzle, or which present a *new* puzzle (by the author) are the ones wanted here. Just 'collecting' puzzles from all over the world is not strictly off-topic, but neither is it encouraged. I would generally advise you to read & participate in the META site for more discussions/feedback on "what is okay/wanted".

Comment: @dmg: *Compound* questions are okay IMHO as well - but only if there is a clear link between them. (i.e. they need a common solution or the solution of one is needed as input for the other). If each puzzle can be solved on its own, it is better to have it split as to not require *compound answers* as well.

Comment: I agree with BmyGuest. Simply copying puzzles somewhere to post them here is not the right way. I personally get the feeling that people do this to attract attention and feel clever (whatever the reason may be). Try to write your own puzzles and you will see that is a lot more fun! It's not that hard and you have a the time you need :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is:

> F. Overlap the rows of pictures to see the top two combine to fill an entire 9-block set. Combine the last row to see a center block is needed.

For the second question, the answer (I think) is:

> A. The first and third pictures and fourth and sixth pictures are reflection across the xy axis. The seventh has an xy axis reflection as choice A.

Edit 1:

For #3, The answer is:

> -5. The top row digit sum equals the sum of the digits below. 9 equals 6+1+2. 3+8 = 3+5+2+1. 4+7=4+2+2+3. 4=(-5)+2+7

For #5, The answer is a similar trick:

> 17. The number below and between each row pair is the sum of their digits. 8+8+6+3=25. 2+5+9=16. 1+6+2+4=13. 1+3+4+9=*17*. To complete, 1+7+1+0=9.

For #4, the answer is:

> H. The top row has all letters with horizontal symmetry (flipped across y axis), and the bottom row has letters with vertical symmetry (flipped across x axis). H is the only letter option that will fit both.

Comment: I don't think 4 and 6 are reflections about the xy axis, won't 6 have to be << for that to be true?

Comment: Imagine the / line over it and think of where the rightmost point would be after reflection, that's how I think of it.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant two reflections instead of a single reflection about the diagonal. Yes, you're right in that case.